# Rpi4B python I2C MCP4725 IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

Tags: raspbian, python

I am working with `MCP4725`. I was working on this quite some time without any issues but currently even the default example given in the [GitHUb Repository](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MCP4725/blob/maste) keeps throwing this error.

```
Press Ctrl-C to quit...
Setting voltage to 0!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "simpletest.py", line 21, in <module>
    dac.set_voltage(0)
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_MCP4725/MCP4725.py", line 
68, in set_voltage
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 129, in 
writeList
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 306, 
in 
write_i2c_block_data
IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

I tried this command `i2cdetect -y 1`

```
      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
  00: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  60: 60 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I am using `Raspberry Pi 4 Model B`. I checked the connections, everything looks good. Can I get some help on this?

Comment: Ah let me see. The following error : "IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error" almost always is caused by a problem in the HARDWARE side of the I2C wiring.  In other words, if your python code always works but not now, then perhaps (1)  wiring disconnected, (2) wiring not disconnected, but layout changes, causing increasing impedance, exceeding the 400pF limit of I2C circuits. To troubleshoot, you can use another I2C device to check if i2cdetect -y 1 can detect that another device. [I assume you tried many times software and hardware (power on reset) and still get the above #121 error.  Cheers.

Comment: PS - rewiring using wires shorter than 30cm might help.  Usually the shorter wires the better.  And daisy chaining wiring is better star network, for less capacitance.  Twisting wiring, using CAT5 cable also helps.

Comment: You are saying the software has not changed but you are now getting errors.  That suggests a change in the hardware.  Not much we can do to help given the information provided.

Comment: I see that the library has been deprecated. There doesn't appear to be any connection issues.

Comment: It appears that the `MCP4725` is not responding to the `Raspberrry p` and not the other way round. How do I resolve this?